# Populate excel cells with sql query tooks so long

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have one excel worksheets with a lot of rows (let's say about 80). For each rows there are about 30-31 columnds (depends of month). Foreach row and foreach column it runs sql query like this:

```
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Do While Worksheets(2).Cells(12 + 0, 1) <> ""
    For i = 13 To lastRow
        For j = 6 To lastColumn

            kodp = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1)

            If Not conn.Execute("SELECT Realization FROm FRM_Raport WHERE EmployeeId=" & kodp & " AND Data=convert(varchar(10), '" & Worksheets(2).Cells(11, j) & "',121 )").EOF Then

                Worksheets(2).Cells(i, j) = Format(conn.Execute("SELECT Realization FROm FRM_RaportWHERE EmployeeId=" & kodp & " AND Data=convert(varchar(10),'" & Worksheets(2).Cells(11, j) & "',121)")!realization/ (60 * 24), "hh:mm")

            End If
        Next j
        i = i + 10
    Next i
```

The problem is, it runs so slow (about 15 minutes to populate whole area). I've tried with Do While loop but it tooks even longer. I've added:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

at the beginning of the sub (ofc i turn it off at the end of sub), but it does not help. Any ideas how to increase performance for that ?

Visualisation of my Excel Sheet:

```
 empty column |  2016-08-01  | 2016-08-02 | ... | 2016-08-30
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 kodp Emp1    |              |            | ... | 
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 kodp Emp2    |              |            | ... |    
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 kodp Emp3    |              |            | ... |        
      .
      .
      .
```

EDIT ! HERE IS WORKING CODE:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
sql = "INSERT INTO temp (colId,rowId,kodp,data) VALUES"
sql3 = "DELETE From temp"
conn.Execute sql3
For i = 13 To lastRow
    kodp = Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 1)
    For j = 6 To lastColumn
        data = Worksheets(2).Cells(11, j)
        sql = sql & "(" & j & "," & i & "," & kodp & ",'" & data & "'),"
    Next
    i = i + 10
Next
sql = Left(sql, Len(sql) - 1)
'MsgBox sql
conn.Execute sql
sql2 = "SELECT t.rowId,t.ColID,Realizacja From Fanar_Raport f INNER JOIN temp t on f.EmployeeId =  t.kodp and f.data=t.data"

Set tmp = conn.Execute(sql2)

Do Until tmp.EOF
    For Each fld In tmp.Fields
        Worksheets(2).Cells(tmp.Fields(0), tmp.Fields(1)) = tmp.Fields(2)
    Next fld
    tmp.MoveNext
Loop

tmp.Close
Set tmp = Nothing
```

Comment: Why are you executing each query twice?  Why not get a recordset and then use it?

Comment: Since you know the min/max dates and the collection of EmployeeId values, you can run a single query to fetch all of the relevant data, then loop over the recordset and populate the grid.  Your performance is mostly bad because of the multiple queries - turning off screenupdating isn't going to fix that.

Comment: Date is not the problem. "kodp" is the problem, cause i cant get all values without any loop.

Comment: `...and EmployeeID in (111,222,333,444,555,666)`. loop over the list of IDs and build up a string to insert into your SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the SQL query just once for all relevant employees and then go through the record set and populate corresponded rows/columns.

UPDATE:  (more details are added)

1. prepare sql query (string variable) like:

   insert into #temp values ((..,..,..,..),('..'..... )

THEN, in one go,

2. create temp table with ColumnID, RowID, EmployeeID, Date
3. run that script to populate temp table
4. run SELECT FROM you table JOINing that temp table ON t1.Employee = t2.Employee AND t1.Date = t2.Date
5. In SELECT you need to specify ColumnID (from temp table), RowID(from temp table) and your Realization.
6. Finally, for each row in the result set, extract column, row number and Realization, and populate corresponded cell.

It should take a few seconds, may be even less.

Comment: Are you sure ? How do i execute this query once if i need to execute it 30 or 31 times for only one Employee because of date ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  Updated my Answer.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get your way.

Comment: If your dates are continuous, like 01/05, 02/05,.... 31/05, then it's even simpler - get first and last date for each employee, and extract Realization for all the dates within the interval  ([date] BETWEEN xxx and yyy) for each employee. It's simpler, but not faster as you need to run it once for each employee.

Comment: Ok... you can go through all cells, right? so initially you need to build the string which looks like insert into #temp (col_id, row_id, employee_id, [date]) values ((1,1,56,'2016-01-01'), (1,2,56,'2016-01-02'), (1,3,56,'2016-01-03')......(<max_row_number>, <max_column_number>, 923, '2016-01-31')). Is it clear for step 1?

Comment: the idea is that you need to upload your excel table to sql server and then run a single select query on the server, so it can quickly process it and return NxM rows where N - number of columns, M - number of rows.

Comment: Running NxM small SELECT queries is much slower than running one large INSERT query + one small SELECT query.

Comment: I'll try and give u feedback.

Comment: It has no any sense. I have to create single string with query which has 600 parts  (30 cols x 20 rows) ???

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'parts'? You need to populate temp table or table variables like in this example: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-insert-multiple-rows-in-one-query-in-SQL - see method #5.  So you have ONE insert, but 600 lines of (col_id, row_id, date) values. Yes, the string will be large, but it will be quick to execute it - it's just 600 rows....almost nothing.

Comment: I'm off in 50 mins, so if you have any questions please ask. And please don't forget to mark the answer as 'Answered' once you get your code working :)

Comment: No. It has to be done in loop, because there is combo box that changing Employees (depends on selection) and combobox changing Month so your way would not work.

Comment: You said that you have the table with a lot of rows - one per employee. So it works for that description that you provided. Yes, implementation may be challenging, but it is worth trying, the execution time will be about seconds or hundreds milliseconds, not minutes. Add more details into original request, and I'll have a look. You have to use a loop to build the query string, not to execute a SQL query for each iteration. This is the reason why it's slow.

Comment: Every row has different "KODP" so it means it belongs to another Employee. There must be loop to go through all Employees

Comment: And? What is the problem? Go though all the employees one by one in a loop and add more and more data to the string variable. You need two loops - one is to build the query string, another one to go through query results to populate the cells. Between the loops you execute the query. ONCE. For ALL employees and for ALL dates.

Comment: fanarek, any progress? Read above Tim's comment - he's proposing the same - building one single query string.

Comment: Anton, i've made big progress. Now, i have problem with populating my worksheet.

Comment: what kind of problem? Your recordset should contain original column and row index, so you just select the cell and assign Realization value to it.  Of course, in a loop.

Comment: No worries. That's great! Just wondering... what is the execution time now after implementing new method?